# Django existing db records not found in testcase when using postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, testcase

ubuntu 22.04, mysql 8.0.35, postgresql 16.1, python 3.8.18, django 4.2

django default db = "mydb"

We have a large data set saved in "mydb", generating that takes a long time.

While using mysql db, I was able to fetch items from "mydb" like `<ModelName>.objects.filter()` in my test cases. I'm unsure if records are copied into "test_" db from "mybd" by django.

Then I switched to postgres, recreated the data. When I fetch the data in APiView, it's working fine. But in testcases all model queries return blank queryset.

Is there a **workaround** for testcases while using postgres so I would **not** have to **recreate** the data every time I run the tests ? Thanks.

Comment: They are not copied no, you should use a *fixture*, or create these *in* the test.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem using fixtures or creating data in the test will take ~20 minutes every time I run tests. Which is why I'm looking for a way to get it working as it was while using mysql. While I was using mysql, testcases were able to fetch the data from the main db, event when a test_ db was created & used by the testcase.

Comment: you can disable recreating the database each time: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb